# AS3 If/If Else problems

Tags: actionscript-3, if-statement

I'm having a problem with If and If Else statements.

I am trying to create a Menu whereby it will generate a movieclip at various predetermined X coordinates.

The problem is that while testing the buttons A, B, C, D, if I click the "A" button, It'll trace "load1" which is a "test" uint as "0" and B SHOULD trace "test" as 1, C as 2 and D as 3.

The thing is that every button I am clicking will have a output of "0" which is the first "if" statement.

Help will be appreciated!

This are the Import statements (Is there any way to Optimize this code? As I still have buttons till "Y")

```
Layout_KeyboardOne.btn_A.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ButtonHandler);
Layout_KeyboardOne.btn_B.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ButtonHandler);
Layout_KeyboardOne.btn_C.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ButtonHandler);
Layout_KeyboardOne.btn_D.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ButtonHandler);
```

This is the ButtonHandler function

```
    if (Layout_KeyboardOne.btn_A)
        {
            load1 = 0;
            trace(load1);
        }
    else if(Layout_KeyboardOne.btn_B)
        {
            load1 = 1;
            trace(load1);
        }
    else if(Layout_KeyboardOne.btn_C)
        {
            load1 = 2;
            trace(load1);
        }
    else if(Layout_KeyboardOne.btn_D)
        {
            load1 = 3;
            trace(load1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the switch statement as it's cleaner and faster if there are more cases.

```
function ButtonHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    switch(e.currentTarget) {
        case Layout_KeyboardOne.btn_A:
            load1 = 0;
            trace(load1);
            break;
        case Layout_KeyboardOne.btn_B:
            load1 = 1;
            trace(load1);
            break;
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The conditional statements in your event handler are not checking which button triggered the event. Instead, they test whether the clip is defined. In your case, the first statement will evaluate to true regardless of which button is clicked because `Layout_KeyboardOne.btn_A` is defined.

One way of distinguishing which instance triggered a particular event is to use the `currentTarget` property of the `Event` object (see [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#currentTarget)):

```
function ButtonHandler(event:Event):void {
    if (event.currentTarget == Layout_KeyboardOne.btn_A) {
         // btn_a was clicked
    }
}
```

Comment: Contains more explanation than my answer, but I still prefer switch over if-else when it comes to more than 2-3 cases. :)

Comment: Agreed. Though the real issue is that OP's conditionals are not checking what OP thinks they're checking.

Answer (score 0):

Switch case will eat your processor for a long list , why dont you use array of object

```
function btnList():array{
      var _btnA:Object={label:"Layout_KeyboardOne.btn_A",load : 0};
      var _btnB:Object={label:"Layout_KeyboardOne.btn_B",load : 1};
       ....
       ....
      var arr:Array = new Array(btnA , btnB ,btnc.....);
      return arr;
      }

       combobox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,mainGoal);
       combobox.labelField = "label";
```

now you can use that list in comboxbox or call anywhere you want to show through loop.

```
for each (var btns:Object in btnList()){
    dropDown.addItem(btns);
}
```

now you can make function to call your desire goal

```
function mainGoal():void{
    var myObject:object = dropdown.selectedItem;
     trace("object label : "+ myObject.label);
     trace("object load  : "+ myObject.load);
     }
```

so this can be example of offline function , it will use much less processor as compare to if else  and switch case .